# Windows Forms Rich Text Box How to Move a Selected Line?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am working on a project at work and I am using a RichTextBox inside of a Windows Forms Project.
I have a simple, small feature that allows me to move a line down a richTextBox, to do so it swaps the
conents of the neighboring lines, unhighlights the previous line, and highlights the next line.

```
// Swap line content    
var lines = rtb.Lines; // rtb is RichTextBox object    
string temp = lines[selectedLine];    
lines[selectedLine] = lines[selectedLine + 1];    
lines[selectedLine+1] = temp;    
rtb.Lines = lines;    

// Set selectedLine and previous Line to proper values    
previousLine = selectedLine;    
selectedLine++;
    
// Highlight    
rtb.Select(rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(previousLine), rtb.Lines[previousLine].Length);    
rtb.SelectionBackColor = rtb.BackColor;    
rtb.Select(rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(selectedLine), rtb.Lines[selectedLine].Length);    
rtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.Cyan;
```

Everything works perfectly, except when I am on line 0 and try to move that line down. In which case aside from line 0 the entire RichTextBox becomes highlighted cyan instead of just line 1.
I have stepped through the program and all the values seem to be correct; in this instance selected line = 1, previous line = 0, and rtb.Lines[selectedLine].Length is the length of the selected line. What is going on here? If this is a limitation/bug of RichTextBox's selection feature, what would be a different way to do this?

Comment: Could you please add the code which initializes `selectedLine` to your example? Without that, it is pretty hard to reproduce the behaviour. I tried `int selectedLine = rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(rtb.SelectionStart);`, and it works fine for me (except the exception you get when the cursor is at the last line).

Comment: Note that in changing the Lines you will loose all previous formatting just as you do when modifying the Text property. Best do it correctly and then test to see if you problem persists..